# Grid view add New Blank row for entry

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a grid view with Textitem Template fields to insert Data into DB.By default One row is loaded for Entry i want to add new row manullay from button click from user in grid view.
My code to make gridview is bellow

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Card_no">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCardNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gross Wt">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtGrossWt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I used the following javascript function to do it but it only add row without text template

```
 var grd = document.getElementById('GridView1');
            var tbod=grd.rows[0].parentNode;
            var newRow=grd.rows[grd.rows.length - 1].cloneNode(true);
            tbod.appendChild(newRow);
            return false;
```

Comment: refer this link
[Adding new rows dynamically in a grid view or datatable in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864991/adding-new-rows-dynamically-in-a-grid-view-or-datatable-in-asp-net?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally utilize the footer row for this

http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/archive/2006/05/04/77151.aspx

Comment: I have dnt any Bounded textbox to Db I want to add only empty duplicate row each time i click the button

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `HeaderTemplate` or `FooterTemplate` for TextBoxes to add a new row. I suggest to try [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx) control.

Comment: I want to add only Empty row as above.I have no any bind field to DB Column I am using vb.net to insert Data to DB

Comment: @user1065397 - That's why I suggest HeaderTemplate/FooterTemplate - in this area you may add unbounded textboxes.

Comment: Then how they will be included to grid for next entry can u plz any example