# Cascading Dropdown List in Gridview: Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0

I have two cascading dropdownlists inside a gridview.  The gridview is bound to a datatable. Prior to adding cascading dropdownlists I had textboxes for each row - this worked fine.  Now after I attempt to add another row to the gridview the project crashes. I tried using an Ajax Update Panel. I tried putting 3 panels - one in each ItemTemplate of the Gridview.  After adding these Ajax Update Panels the page wouldn't load because it couldn't find the button from the gridview footer.

What should I try? I want validation turned on.

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SetInitialRow();
        }
    }

        private void SetInitialRow()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ItemType", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Job", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UnitPrice", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("LineTotal", typeof(string)));

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
        dr["ItemType"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Description"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Job"] = string.Empty;
        dr["UnitPrice"] = string.Empty;
        dr["LineTotal"] = "$0.00";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        gvPO.DataSource = dt;
        gvPO.DataBind();
    }

        private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {

        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            DataRow drNewRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)gvPO.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("QuantityTextBox");
                    DropDownList dropdwn1 = (DropDownList)gvPO.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddlItemType");
                    DropDownList dropdwn2 = (DropDownList)gvPO.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddlItems");
                    TextBox box4 = (TextBox)gvPO.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("JobTextBox");
                    TextBox box5 = (TextBox)gvPO.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("UnitPriceTextBox");
                    Label lbl1 = (Label)gvPO.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("LineTotalLabel");

                    try
                    {
                        double dbl1 = 0.0;
                        double dbl2 = 0.0;
                        bool bResult1 = false;
                        bool bResult2 = false;

                        String str1 = box1.Text;
                        String str2 = box5.Text;

                        bResult1 = (double.TryParse(str1, out dbl1));
                        bResult2 = (double.TryParse(str2, out dbl2));

                        dbl2 = dbl1 * dbl2;

                        if (bResult1 && bResult2)
                        {
                            lbl1.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", dbl2);
                            lbl1.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception except)
                    {
                        lbl1.Text = "$0.00";
                        lbl1.Visible = true;
                        String strError = "<br /><span style=\"color:red; font-weight:bold\">";
                        strError += except.ToString();
                        strError += "</span><br />";

                        Response.Write(strError);

                    }

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
                    drCurrentRow["Quantity"] = box1.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["ItemType"] = dropdwn1.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    drCurrentRow["Description"] = dropdwn2.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    drCurrentRow["Job"] = box4.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["UnitPrice"] = box5.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["LineTotal"] = lbl1.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }

                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                //Store the current data to ViewState
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                //Rebind the Grid with the current data
                gvPO.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                gvPO.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }

        private void SetPreviousData()
    {

        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)gvPO.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("QuantityTextBox");
                    DropDownList dropdwn1 = (DropDownList)gvPO.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddlItemType");
                    DropDownList dropdwn2 = (DropDownList)gvPO.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddlItems");
                    TextBox box4 = (TextBox)gvPO.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("JobTextBox");
                    TextBox box5 = (TextBox)gvPO.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("UnitPriceTextBox");
                    Label lbl1 = (Label)gvPO.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("LineTotalLabel");

                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Quantity"].ToString();
                    dropdwn1.SelectedItem.Value = dt.Rows[i]["ItemType"].ToString();
                    dropdwn2.SelectedItem.Value = dt.Rows[i]["Description"].ToString();
                    box4.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Job"].ToString();
                    box5.Text = dt.Rows[i]["UnitPrice"].ToString();
                    lbl1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["LineTotal"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

        <asp:GridView ID="gvPO" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDataBound="gvPO_DataBound" Width="800px" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E2E8F3" Width="100%" />
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        Empty Grid
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="trBackLightBlueAlternate" />
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" >
        <ItemStyle Width="0%" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QTY">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="QuantityTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" MaxLength="4" Width="100%" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FiltTextBoxExtQuantity" runat="server" TargetControlID="QuantityTextBox" FilterType="Numbers"></asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="8%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ITEM TYPE">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelAjax" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItemType" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDown1" runat="server" TargetControlID="ddlItemType" ServicePath="~/ItemList.asmx" 
                        ServiceMethod="GetItemTypes" LoadingText="[loading...]" PromptText="[select item type]" Category="ItemTypeID"></asp:CascadingDropDown>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="22%" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DESCRIPTION">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelAjax2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItems" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDown2" runat="server" TargetControlID="ddlItems" ServicePath="~/ItemList.asmx"
                        ServiceMethod="GetItemsForItemTypes" ParentControlID="ddlItemType" LoadingText="[loading...]"
                        PromptText="[select item]" Category="Description">
                    </asp:CascadingDropDown>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40%" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="JOB">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="JobTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" Width="100%" ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UNIT PRICE">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="UnitPriceTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" Width="100%" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="UnitPriceTextBox" ValidChars="1234567890.$"></asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LINE TOTAL">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LineTotalLabel" runat="server" Width="100%" ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="ADD NEW ROW" CssClass="btnStyle1" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" Width="100%" CausesValidation="True" />
        </FooterTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I took autopostback off my dropdownlists and I get:  Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: The code I'm using is just like this, but edited for my needs: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864991/adding-new-rows-dynamically-in-a-grid-view-or-datatable-in-asp-net)