# Add new rows to Asp.net grid view without refresh previous rows values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I have a grid view with two columns text box and drop down list when I add values and click "ADD" button I want to add new row with Previous values,
I do it but my previous values refresh. Please help me.
This is my aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvStudent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListAddress" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"> </asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Address1" Value="1"> </asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Address2" Value="2"> </asp:ListItem>

                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    <div>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonADD" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="ButtonADD_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is my output 
[image]

This is my CodeBehind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SetInitialRow();
        }
    }

    private void SetInitialRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Address", typeof(string)));

        dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr["Name"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Address"] = string.Empty;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        ViewState["StudentTable"] = dt;

        gvStudent.DataSource = dt;
        gvStudent.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ButtonADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add Rows 
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Are you calling `SetInitialRow()` in `ButtonADD_Click`? You need to extract values from `GridView` before postback and save them in `DataTable` and rebind them.

Comment: no I only called SetInitialRow() in page load. Can you send me example please

Comment: check this link out very simple code [Add new rows dynamically in a grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864991/adding-new-rows-dynamically-in-a-grid-view-or-datatable-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 stpes to do it:

1. Get data from GridView and save to datatable
2. Add new row to datatable and save datatable to viewstate
3. Bind datatable to gridview

   ```
   private void SaveGridViewDataIntoDataTable()
   {
       DataTable StudentTable = ViewState["StudentTable"] as DataTable;

       foreach (GridViewRow row in gvStudent.Rows)
       {
           //get ddl value
           DropDownList  DropDownListAddress = row.FindControl("DropDownListAddress") as DropDownList;
           StudentTable.Rows[row.RowIndex]["Address"] = DropDownListAddress.SelectedValue;

           //get name from textbox
           TextBox TextBoxName = row.FindControl("TextBoxName") as TextBox;
           StudentTable.Rows[row.RowIndex]["Name"] = TextBoxName.Text;
       }

       ViewState["StudentTable"] = StudentTable;
   }

   private void AddNewRowToGridView()
   {
       SaveGridViewDataIntoDataTable();

       DataTable StudentTable = ViewState["StudentTable"] as DataTable;
       StudentTable.Rows.Add("Name", "Select");

       gvStudent.DataSource = StudentTable;
       gvStudent.DataBind();
   }
   ```

**now subscribe to Gridview RowBound event**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStudent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvStudent_RowDataBound">
```

**also add "RowIndex" Attribute to any of your gridview controls**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" runat="server" RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void gvStudent_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //get name from textbox
        TextBox TextBoxName = row.FindControl("TextBoxName") as TextBox;

        //get ddl value
        DropDownList DropDownListAddress = row.FindControl("DropDownListAddress") as DropDownList;

        //get rowindex
        int RowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxName.Attributes["RowIndex"]);

        //get datatable stored in viewstate
        DataTable StudentTable = ViewState["StudentTable"] as DataTable;

        //assign values to controls
        TextBoxName.Text = StudentTable.Rows[RowIndex]["Name"].ToString();
        DropDownListAddress.SelectedValue = StudentTable.Rows[RowIndex]["Address"].ToString();
    }
}
```